Writing a query regarding deduplication of data
I have a table POTENTIAL_MASTER where the potential for each PRODUCT is stored.
I have a list of products in the column PRODUCT like this:
ENGLISH, TAMIL, HINDI, URDU, TELUGU

The potential for TAMIL and TELUGU are the same always. If the potential is for TAMIL, it also applied for TELUGU.
Now when I calculated the sum of potential for all products, I should get only one value for TAMIL and TELUGU. For ex: potential of tamil and telugu is 20. The query should consider only one 20 value.
Can you someone guide me how to do that?
I tried distinct, union statements but the potential is taken twice.
I want the sum of potential where only one value either TAMIL or TELUGU is taken into account

Please add sample data in the form of a table with columns.

And the result you want to achieve, based on that sample data

Can a row contain more than 1 product (language) value?
It seems there are 5 products (language) options, and you want to treat TAMIL and TELUGU as the same.
If a row can contain either TAMIL OR TELUGU, does that count as 1 product with potential = 20?
If a row can contain either TAMIL AND TELUGU, does that count as 1 product with potential = 20?

It looks like you want to treat TAMIL and TELUGU as interchangeable.
So we can create a CTE of them substituted with a single value and assigned the same potential value of 20.
WITH 
  --create a table of POTENTIAL_MASTER since it hasn't been supplied
  POTENTIAL_MASTER AS (
    SELECT "ENGLISH" AS product, 10 as potential
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "TAMIL",20
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "HINDI",17
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "URDU",35
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "TELUGU",20
  ),

  --treat TAMIL and TELUGU as the same product
  POTENTIAL_MASTER_CLEAN AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      CASE
        WHEN product in ("TAMIL","TELUGU") THEN "TAMIL/TELUGU"
        ELSE product
      END AS product,
      CASE
        WHEN product in ("TAMIL","TELUGU") THEN 
          (
            (SELECT potential FROM POTENTIAL_MASTER WHERE product = "TAMIL") +
            (SELECT potential FROM POTENTIAL_MASTER WHERE product = "TELUGU")
          ) / 2
        ELSE potential
      END AS potential
    FROM POTENTIAL_MASTER
  )

SELECT 
  product,
  CAST(potential AS INT64) AS potential
FROM POTENTIAL_MASTER_CLEAN

Output:
product      potential
ENGLISH      10
TAMIL/TELUGU 20
HINDI        17
URDU         35

Now you can sum the potential for the product values, with TAMIL + TELUGU only counting once.
